# Charts in SwiftUI as Bubble Chart

Tags: charts, swiftui

I get the bubble chart to work using Charts in SwiftUI with the following:

ViewModel sets the data:

```
func bubbleEntries() -> [BubbleChartDataEntry] {
    
    return [
         
        BubbleChartDataEntry(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, size: CGFloat(20)),
        BubbleChartDataEntry(x: 1.0, y: 1.0, size: CGFloat(6)),
        BubbleChartDataEntry(x: 2.0, y: 1.0, size: CGFloat(8)),
        BubbleChartDataEntry(x: 3.0, y: 1.0, size: CGFloat(2)),
         
    ]

}
```

then it goes to the UIViewRepresentable"

```
struct BubbleChart : UIViewRepresentable {

    var entries : [BubbleChartDataEntry] 

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> BubbleChartView {
   
        let chart = BubbleChartView()
       
        chart.data = addData()
        return chart
    
    }
 
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: BubbleChartView, context: Context) {
        uiView.data = addData()
    }
  
    func addData( ) -> BubbleChartData {
    
       let data = BubbleChartData()

       let dataSet = BubbleChartDataSet(entries: entries )
     
       data.addDataSet(dataSet)
    
       return data
    
    }

    typealias UIViewType = BubbleChartView

}
```

And all is good.

[image]

But if I want to style the data I loose the size?

So if I change to this:

```
func addData( ) -> BubbleChartData {
    
    let data = BubbleChartData()

    let dataSet = self.entries

    let set0 = BubbleChartDataSet(entries: [dataSet[0]], label: "Dog")
    set0.drawIconsEnabled = false
    set0.setColor(ChartColorTemplates.colorful()[0], alpha: 0.5)
    set0.drawValuesEnabled = true
    data.addDataSet(set0)

    let set1 = BubbleChartDataSet(entries: [dataSet[1]], label: "Cat")
    set1.drawIconsEnabled = false
    set1.setColor(ChartColorTemplates.colorful()[1], alpha: 0.5)
    set1.drawValuesEnabled = true
    data.addDataSet(set1)


    return data
    
}
```

Somehow the data now returns this and the size variable is missing.

It changes from a BubbleChartDataEntry to a ChartDataEntry.

```
[ChartDataEntry, x: 0.0, y 1.0, ChartDataEntry, x: 1.0, y 1.0, ChartDataEntry, x: 2.0, y 1.0, ChartDataEntry, x: 3.0, y 1.0]
```

The chart still works without the size.

What am i missing?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BubbleChartDataSet shows relative sizes, so if you set one element per set the size is always default one. Instead you need to set colors for values within one set.

Try the following:

```
func addData( ) -> BubbleChartData {

   let data = BubbleChartData()

   let dataSet = BubbleChartDataSet(entries: entries )
   // assuming your `colorful` has same count as entries, otherwise you
   // you have to created explicit array of entries colors
   dataSet.valueColors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful() 
 
   data.addDataSet(dataSet)

   return data

}
```

Comment: that will hance the Value colors - not the colors for the bubbles.  thanks.

Comment: dataSet.setColors(ChartColorTemplates.colorful(), alpha: 0.5)